# Removing last vowels from every word in a sentence javascript

Tags: javascript

> Write a function that removes the last vowel in each word in a sentence.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> removeLastVowel("Those who dare to fail miserably can achieve greatly.") 
>  ➞ "Thos wh dar t fal miserbly cn achiev gretly."
>
> removeLastVowel("Love is a serious mental disease.") 
>  ➞ "Lov s  serios mentl diseas"
>
> removeLastVowel("Get busy living or get busy dying.") 
>  ➞ "Gt bsy livng r gt bsy dyng"
> ```

What I am doing is

```
  function sumDigProd(arr) {
  let ans = arr.split(" ");
  let array = [];
  for (i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ans[i].length; j++) {
      var vowelAtLast;
      if (
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "a" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "e" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "i" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "o" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "u"
      ) {
        vowelAtLast = ans[i][j];
      }
    }
    var idex = ans[i].lastIndexOf(vowelAtLast);
    console.log(idex,ans[i],ans[i][idex]);
    ans[i].replace(ans[i][idex],'')
    array.push(ans[i])
    console.log(ans)
  }
  console.log(ans)
  return array.join(" ");
}

console.log(sumDigProd("youuo goalo people."));
```

Here, `console.log(idex,ans[i],ans[i][idex]);` gives me the correct output for example:

```
4 "youuo" "o"
```

But now when I try to do:

```
ans[i].replace(ans[i][idex],'')
console.log(ans)
```

I get

```
["youuo", "goalo", "people."]
```

again instead i should get

```
["youu", "goalo", "people."]
```

after the first time loop runs... and then at last I get the output as

```
["youu", "goal", "peopl."]
```

as per the problem but I get

```
["youuo", "goalo", "people."]
```

why are no changes made by the `replace` method here?

Comment: The result is always the empty string ATM, since the `array` array starts out empty and is never referenced until it's returned

Comment: @CertainPerformance yea my fault but before that i am not getting what i need i,e console.log(ans) is giving the wrong output thats what troubling me

Comment: Read up on replace() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem is that

```
ans[i].replace(ans[i][idex], '')
```

will only replace the *first* occurrence of whatever character `ans[i][idex]` is. Eg

```
aza
```

would result in

```
za
```

Another issue is that you must use the return value of `.replace`, else it'll go unused and be irrelevant; you'd want something like

```
ans[i] = ans[i].replace(ans[i][idex], '')
```

instead, so that the item at that index in the array is properly reassigned.

But it would probably be easier to use a regular expression: match a vowel, followed by *capturing* zero or more non-vowels in a capture group, with lookahead matching a space or the end of the string. Then replace with the first capture group, thereby removing the last vowel:

```js
const sumDigProd = str => str.replace(
  /[aeiou]([^aeiou]*?)(?= |$)/gi,
  '$1'
);

console.log(sumDigProd("youuo goalo people."));
```

`[aeiou]([^aeiou]*?)(?= |$)` means:

- `[aeiou]` - Any vowel
- `([^aeiou]*?)` - Match and capture:

  - `[^aeiou]*?` Any non-vowel, lazily (capture group), up until
- `(?= |$)` - lookahead matches a space or the end of the string

Then

- `'$1'` - Replace with the capture group

To change your *original* code, identify the last index of a vowel by iterating from the final index of the string and going backwards. When one is found, reassign the string at `ans[i]` and `.slice`ing the portions behind and in front of the found vowel:

```js
function sumDigProd(arr) {
  let ans = arr.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
    for (j = ans[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      if (
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "a" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "e" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "i" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "o" ||
        ans[i][j].toLowerCase() == "u"
      ) {
        ans[i] = ans[i].slice(0, j) + ans[i].slice(j + 1);
        // go to next word
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return ans.join(' ');
}

console.log(sumDigProd("youuo goalo people."));
```

Comment: but my idex gives the index of last occureance of the vowel so why is my first vowel getting replaced ?

Comment: `replace` would replace only the first occurrence of its first parameter in the string, not the one at a particular index. It's not really the right function for the job you're trying to do, which is remove a character at a specific index. Use `ans[i] = ans[i].slice(0, idex) + ans[i].slice(idex + 1);` if the regex is a bit too advanced.

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai *why is my first vowel getting replaced* Because you're calling `.replace` without using the resulting string (and because you wouldn't always be replacing the correct vowel) - see the first part of the answer